# Show that the direct sum $f\oplus g:X\to\textbf{R}^{2}$ defined by $f\oplus g(x) = (f(x),g(x))$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

Let $(X,d_{X})$ be a metric space, and let $f:X\to\textbf{R}$ and $g:X\to\textbf{R}$ be uniformly continuous functions. Show that the direct sum $f\oplus g:X\to\textbf{R}^{2}$ defined by $f\oplus g(x) = (f(x),g(x))$ is uniformly continuous.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let $\varepsilon/2 > 0$. Then there exist $\delta_{1} > 0$ and $\delta_{2} > 0$ such that for every $x,y\in X$
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
d_{X}(x,y) < \delta_{1} \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon/2\\\\
d_{X}(x,y) < \delta_{2} \Rightarrow |g(x) - g(y)| < \varepsilon/2
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Let us equip $\textbf{R}^{2}$ with the Euclidean metric. Since the following inequality holds
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{|f(x) - f(y)|^{2} + |g(x) - g(y)|^{2}} \leq |f(x) - f(y)| + |g(x) - g(y)|
\end{align*}
for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there corresponds a $\delta = \min\{\delta_{1},\delta_{2}\}$ such that for every $x,y\in X$
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{|f(x) - f(y)|^{2} + |g(x) - g(y)|^{2}} \leq |f(x) - f(y)| + |g(x) - g(y)| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
whenever $d_{X}(x,y) < \delta$, and the proposed result is valid.

Does anyone want to make any suggestion or critique? Any of them are welcome.

Comment: The statement "$f \oplus g$ is continuous" is in the format "for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta>0$" (and similarly for "$f$ is continous" (A) and "$g$ is continuous" (B)). Then the first statement of the proof should be "Let $\epsilon > 0$". Then use the statement of A and B to find a $\delta$. Note that when we say "$f$ is continuous" means "for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists ...", the $\epsilon$ here and the $\epsilon$ from the definition of $f \oplus g$ are "not the same".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely correct, but I'd like to make 2 small nitpicks:

1. It's probably better to start the proof by saying "Let $\varepsilon > 0$" (and if you like you can proceed to say "so that $\varepsilon/2 > 0$"), because $\varepsilon$ is the thing you really need to pick arbitrarily.
2. It only makes sense to ask if a function is uniformly continuous when its domain and codomain are metric spaces: if you haven't specified a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, it doesn't even make sense to ask if $f \oplus g$ is uniformly continuous. So you don't get to make the choice of which metric to equip $\mathbb{R}^2$ with, but you're right that the Euclidean metric is (probably) what's intended here. You should rephrase your homework solution(?) to begin with "I will assume that $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the standard Euclidean metric", or something like that.